# Issue with QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I'm doing a Qt project where I'm having some `QLineEdit` that whatever I put into them it doesn't get any data, and in others I don't have this problem. Also in some of them if I only put in there one char it still thinks that I have nothing and then I cant erase that char. I tried using `textChanged` and `editingFinished` signals but it still doesn't work. This is what I tried:

```
void MainWindow::on_numExt_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    ui->numExt->setText( arg1 );
}
```

where `numExt` is the `QLineEdit` name, sometimes I have to press enter and I get the text but it doesn't work all the times

this is the declaration of the `QLineEdit`:

```
<widget class="QLineEdit" name="numExt">
    <property name="font">
        <font>
            <pointsize>6</pointsize>
        </font>
    </property>
 </widget>
```

and in the ui_mainwindow.h file appears like this:

```
numExt = new QLineEdit(frame_5);
numExt->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("numExt"));
numExt->setFont(font);
```

here im used it to save its value into a db

```
insertQuery = "update content set calle='" + ui->calle->text().toUtf8() + "', numExt='"+ ui->numExt->text().toUtf8() +"', numInt='"+ ui->numInt->text().toUtf8() +"', colonia='" + ui->colonia->text().toUtf8() + "', CP='" + ui->CP->text().toUtf8() + "' where folio='" + ui->Folio->text().toUtf8() + "'"; 
query.exec(insertQuery);
```

I didn't change any attribute of the form.

My goal is to get the text that is in the qlineedit, it doesn't matter if I input 1 character or more.

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code example doesn't make any sense. The textChanged slot is called when the QLineEdit's text changes. Then you set the changed text back to the QLineEdit. Why?

Comment: because ui->numExt->text() returns me empty string wherever input I gave, so I tried to force the QLineEdit to set that text

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here, but I can tell you that setting the text of numExt to arg1 in response to numExt's textChanged or editingFinished signal is, at best, redundant. Perhaps if you could clarify the question a bit, someone could provide an answer?

Comment: My question is why ui->QLineEdit->text() send me empty string in various cases when I prevously wrote down something in it, this is the solution I found but I need to press enter everytime I finish editing so the value is saved

Comment: That certainly doesn't sound right. Can you provide more of the code? Or perhaps boil it down to a simple example that duplicates the problem and post that?

Comment: I add how the qlineedit is declared I hope it helps and how im use it

Comment: Try to connect to `editingFinished()`. This way when the QLineEdit loses focus you can safely extract the text.

Comment: You really don't need any signals/slots to make your insertQuery line work. If there's text in the lineedit, text() will return what is there.

Comment: the problem is that text() is empty unless I hit Intro after adding a text into the qlineedit

Comment: I agree with Wes, below. Try using cout or QDebug to print the value of the text field to the console before you try to make your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to run a debugger like the one in QtCreator and see what your values are when you:

1. type something into the field
2. whats being sent back to the field

This will narrow it down more as to where the issue lies.
ie: If it's in the saving of the data, or the retrieving of the data.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a race condition with the above code.  If you're actually binding a signal/slot to modifying the same object you'll run into trouble.  You generally shouldn't be changing the text that is being edited right at the same time it's being edited.  To make it more complex, remember that there is no guarantee that the LineEdit block won't emit multiple signals before you slot actually gets called to handle them.  It all depends on when the event loop actually has the break to process everything.

In short: don't do that.  Describe instead what your end goal is instead and maybe we can find the real source of your problem.

Comment: I agree!!!!!!!! [I had to type that many !s to get over the minimum character limit.  Of course, now with this addition....]

Comment: It sends me empty string, but if I hit intro key it returns the value I entered